# java struts2 hibernate and spring application and soap web services

Tags: java, spring, soap, struts2, action-mapping

I have a web application using struts2, spring and hibernate frameworks. Now I want to expose some of its methods via soap web service. I have a class and I simply annotated it with `@WebService` annotation and an Service endpoint interface. Now when I deploy my application on glassfish it deploys fine but when I try to access wsdl via glasssfish admin console. It gives me the following error.

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [UsersControllerImplService] associated with context path [/ossoc].
```

I understand its something related to configuration but I am unable to figure out what configuration.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

        <display-name>ossoc</display-name>


         <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

    </web-app>
```

struts2.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />

    <package name="user"  namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="authentication" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor"></interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="authStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="authentication"></interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="authStack"></default-interceptor-ref>

         <global-results>
            <result name="login" type="redirect">/index.action</result>
        </global-results>

        <action name="register" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.RegisterAction">
          <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
          <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
          <result name="error">/register.jsp</result>
          <result name="input">/register.jsp</result>  
        </action>

        <action name="login" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.LoginAction">
          <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
          <result name="success">/user/home.jsp</result>
          <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>
          <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>  
        </action>

        <action name="activate" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.ActivateAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success">/user/home.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
         </action>



        <action name="index">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="home">
            <result>/user/home.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="showfiles" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.ShowFiles">
            <result name="success">/user/files.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="edit">
            <result>/user/edit.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="logout" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.LogoutAction">
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="changepassword" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.ChangePassword">
            <result name="success">/user/edit.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="upload" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.UploadFile">
            <result>/user/home.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="showgrid" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.ShowFiles">
            <result name="success">/user/files.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="deletefile" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.DeleteFile">
            <result name="success">/user/files.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="downloadfile" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.core.actions.DownloadFile">
            <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentType"></param>
                <param name="inputName"></param>
                <param name="contentDisposition"></param>
                <param name="bufferSize"></param>
                <param name="allowCaching"></param>
                <param name="contentLength"></param>
            </result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

applicationCOntext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">

        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


        <!-- Database Configuration -->

    <import resource="DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="HibernateSessionFactory.xml"/>

    <!-- Beans Declaration -->
    <import resource="UsersBean.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: What url you enter in the browser that can't map to the action in your configuration?

Comment: @RomanC in glassfish admin console this is the link 
http://localhost:8080/ossoc/UsersControllerImplService?wsdl

Answer (score 2):

Why everyone here is so eager to vote down.

This was the problem.
In `web.xml` the struts2 filter has `/* url pattern` mapped so struts2 will filter every request that comes to it including the request to the webservice servlet. Since filters execute before servlets so I was getting the action not mapped error. 
From the struts2 documentation.
The action mapping extension has been changed to .action plus "" it means if I simply enter name of servlet in the address bar the struts2 will take it as action and check struts2.xml for relevant action mapping since there are no action mapping so it will throw error.

Solution
I just add the .extension after url in URL pattern mapping so struts2 will treat as a servlet request other option will to use

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="URLTOEXCLUDE"/> 
and configure the webservice to use the excluded URL
```

Hope this helps others.